# ¿Cómo utilizar varios botones submit en un formulario en PHP MVC?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mvc

tengo un formulario donde muestro los datos en una tabla y este al seleccionarlo una fila me devuelve los datos en un modal, en ese modal tengo 3 botones y quisiera saber como le asigno distintas funciones de mi controlador. Este es el código "simplificado" que utilizo:

```
<form method="POST">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">REASIGNAR</button>';
       $AsignarArea = new ControladorExpediente();
        $AsignarArea->ctrAsignarArea();
```

- Y luego quisiera otro botón, lo trate de hacer con "formaction":

  ```
  <button type="submit" class="form-control btn-primary" formaction="<?php
       $cancelarExpe = new ControladorExpediente();
       $cancelarExpe->ctrexpedienteCancelar(); ?>">CANCELAR
    </button>
  ```

[image: Así Muestro los botones]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes tener varios botones tipo *submit*, de preferencia, todos con el mismo nombre y asignando valor directamente para poder realizar comparaciones al procesar.

```
<form method="POST" action="ruta/controlador/mas-info">
    <!-- Aquí tus campos y luego los botones -->
    <button type="submit" name="accion" value="reasignar">Reasignar</button>
    <button type="submit" name="accion" value="atender">Atender Expediente</button>
    <button type="submit" name="accion" value="cancelar">Cancelar Expediente</button>
</form>
```

El funcionamiento es similar a los campos tipo *radio*, enviando solo el botón que recibió clic, por lo que en PHP solo debes analizar el valor, pero primero debes asegurate de haberlo recibido o asignar un valor por defecto; sugiero el [operador de fusión NULL](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

```
<?php
// Si el valor no está en $_POST, asignar cadena vacía
$accion = $_POST['accion'] ?? '';
// Buscar qué botón fue el que se usó para enviar el formulario
if($accion == 'reasignar') {
    // Inicializar y ejecutar controlador correspondiente
    $AsignarArea = new ControladorExpediente();
    $AsignarArea->ctrAsignarArea();
} elseif($accion == 'atender') {
    // Inicializar y ejecutar controlador correspondiente
} elseif($accion == 'cancelar') {
    // Inicializar y ejecutar controlador correspondiente
} else {
    // Acción inválida... lanzar excepción o mostrar error
}
```

Comment: Justo es lo que estaba buscando, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En vez de usar varios.submit puedes usar varias etiquetas , por ejemplo:

```
<a href="javascript;:" onClick="funcionCuandoDaClick(<?= $modelo->id?>);">CANCELAR EXPEDIENTE</a>
```

Ya dentro de la función puedes mandar a llamar un AJAX o bien si lo que quieres es cambiar la pantalla puedes usar el href directamente

```
<a href="/atender-expediente/<?= $modelo->id ?>">ATENDER EXPEDIENTE</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Este ejemplo que estoy a punto de usar, es un ejemplo de como yo suelo solucionar tomando en cuenta si el concepto de **controlador** del lado del cliente lo realizas por medio de una peticion **evitando** el evento por default de la etiqueta `<a>`. Ten en cuenta que respecto a tu pregunta, no veo el caso de que se refreque la ventana una vez que uno de los botones ha sido presionado, ya que por lo que logro entender es que deben verse estos resultados de presionar alguno de los botones en el modal, asi que asumire que realizaras peticiones async con AJAX

Nota: Perdon mi falta de acentos, tengo teclado en ingles :3

ej.

```php
<a onclick="ejecutaLlamada('<?= $accion_reasignar ?>')">REASIGNAR</a>
<a onclick="ejecutaLlamada('<?= $accion_cancelar ?>')">CANCELAR EXPEDIENTE</a>
<a onclick="ejecutaLlamada('<?= $accion_atender ?>')">ATENDER EXPEDIENTE</a>
```

Una vez hecho esto, podemos pasar a realizar la peticion por medio de AJAX. Ya en este caso dependera de que libreria o API uses ya sea **$.ajax** de jQuery, **axios** o **fetch** una API nativa de JavaScript en los navegadores modernos.

Yo usare **axios** por costumbre, pero son muy similares las tres.

JS ej.

```javascript
function ejecutaLlamada(accion) {
    axios('path/a/tu/sitio/' + accion, {
        method: '<GET|POST|PUT|DELETE>', // Dependera de de que accion realices
        data: JSON.stringify({...}),     // Tus datos a enviar solo sin son POST, PUT O DELETE, para GET es directamente un Query string, es decir directamente en la URL
        dataType: 'json',                // Dependera de que necesites, yo por lo general uso JSON
    })
    .then(res => res.data)
    .then(json => {
        // Haces algo con los datos como ya ponerlos en el MODAL
    }).catch(error => {
        // Haces algo si la peticion salio mal
    });
}
```

Esta es la forma en que yo por lo general lo hago, puede que sea lo que necesites por lo que logro entender de la pregunta.